# Jquery Mobile changePage failing inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, iframe

I'm working with a page that writes a JQuery Mobile page into an iframe by setting the iFrame's innerHTML from the parent page.  This works on Mobile Safari, where the iFrame is somehow given a URI of applewebdata://72559F4F-AF32-4B68-A7FC-11198E6830AD/, but in Chrome the iFrame's URI is about:blank (which is what I would expect).

The problem seems to be that when I try to use changePage() to change the page to a div with an id of, for example, #Question_1, JQM seems to be trying to navigate to about:blank/#Question_1.

I'm hoping there's a way to make this work without having to open an HTML file.

Is there a way to 'assign' a URI to an iFrame that has been created and populated from JavaScript?  Is there some other method I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable *hash change* when using `changePage` function.

- jQM 1.4

  ```
  $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#page", { changeHash: false });
  ```
- jQM 1.0 - 1.3

  ```
  $.mobile.changePage("#page", { changeHash: false });
  ```

Or disable it globally once and for all on `mobileinit` event, after loading jQuery and before loading jQuery Mobile.

```
<head>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
      $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
    });
  </script>
  <script src="jquery.mobile.js"></script>
</head>
```